# At a specific point in a magnetic field, how can there be a direction if there is no magnitude?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I am taught that there is no magnetic force on a moving charge if the charge moves along the direction of the magnetic field. That would mean that the magnitude of the magnetic field at that point would be zero. However, I am also taught that to find the direction of a point in a magnetic field, one needs to see the direction of the "north" needle of a compass at that particular point. If the magnitude of the magnetic field at that point is zero, how could the compass point in any direction and hence how could we know what the direction of the magnetic field at that point?

The situation mentioned in the first sentence of the previous paragraph could not possibly exist, right?

Comment: Hint: 0 magnetic force on a body at a point $\ne$ 0 magnetic field at that point

Comment: "...That would mean that the magnitude of the magnetic field at that point would be zero" not always true as pointed out by @Nihar Karve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am taught that there is no magnetic force on a moving charge if the
> charge moves along the direction of the magnetic field. That would
> mean that the magnitude of the magnetic field at that point would be
> zero.

Careful: the second statement does not follow from the first. If we adopt a rectangular system of coordinates (e.g. the standard $x,y,z$ coordinates) then the formula for the force on a point charge $q$ in a magnetic field $\bf B$ is
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
f_x &=& q (v_y B_z - v_z B_y) \\
f_y &=& q (v_z B_x - v_x B_z) \\
f_z &=& q (v_x B_y - v_y B_x)
\end{array}
$$
(This can also be written ${\bf f} = q {\bf v} \times {\bf B}$ but I want this answer to be accessible to people who don't know that notation). For example, if the velocity $\bf v$ is in the $x$ direction and the field is in the $y$ direction then these equations give
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
f_x &=& q (0  0 - 0 0) = 0 \\
f_y &=& q (0  0 - 0 0) = 0\\
f_z &=& q (v B - 0 0) = q v B
\end{array}
$$
so in this case the force is in the $z$ direction with a magnitude $q v B$. So far so good.

Now let's see what happens when the velocity and the magnetic field are both in the same direction, say the $x$ direction. Now we find
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
f_x &=& q (0 0 - 0 0) = 0 \\
f_y &=& q (0 B - v 0) = 0\\
f_z &=& q (v 0 - 0 B) = 0
\end{array}
$$
So now the force is zero but the magnetic field is not. So a zero force does *not* imply a zero field. What would imply a zero field is if the force came out zero no matter what direction the particle was travelling in.

Finally, in the case of a zero field you do indeed have a situation where it is not possible to assign a direction to the field. As a mathematical statement, that is true. But in physics it is hard to get a truly zero field. One can obtain a field whose magnitude is zero at some particular point, but near that point it would typically be not quite exactly zero (because it is so hard to get a strictly uniform field). In this case what happens is that one can assign a direction to the field at any location near to but not exactly at the special point.